# How to handle `Link` header with Ballerina http client?

Tags: http, hateoas, ballerina

Some APIs return the next page information (in pagination) as the `Link` header. Is there a way in Ballerina to parse the `Link` header and refer the different links?

An example set of `Link` headers are below:

```
Link: <https://[hostname]/config/v2/menus?pageSize=1>; rel="first"1
Link: <https://[hostname]/config/v2/menus?pageSize=1&page=5>; rel="self"2
Link: <https://[hostname]/config/v2/menus?pageSize=1&page=4>; rel="prev"3
Link: <https://[hostname]/config/v2/menus?pageSize=1&page=6>; rel="next"4
Link: <https://[hostname]/config/v2/menus?pageSize=1&page=10>; rel="last"
```

PS: Ballerina already supports links in the body ([HATEOAS](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-standard-library/issues/1637))

Answer (score 2):

In Ballerina, the `Link` header is treated similarly to any other HTTP headers since how you want to handle the `Link` header depends on your application's specific requirements. Therefore, you can use the `http:parseHeader()` function to parse the `Link` header.

Here's an example:

```
public function main() returns error? {
    http:Response res = new;
    res.addHeader("Link", "<https://[hostname]/v2/menus?pageSize=1>; rel=\"first\"");

    string linkHeader = check res.getHeader("Link");
    var parsedLinkHeader = check http:parseHeader(linkHeader);
    // [
    //     {
    //         "value": "<https://[hostname]/v2/menus?pageSize=1>",
    //         "params": {
    //             "rel": "first"
    //         }
    //     }
    // ]
}
```

In the above example, the resulting parsed link header is an array of header values, each of which has a `value` field and a `params` field. The value field contains the actual link URL, and the params field contains any other parameters specified in the `Link` header.